# macAfter a few seconds after running the ssh command, the process will exit in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, ssh, terminal, ssh-tunnel

I wrote a script file to start the SSH tunnel and I run the path of the script file using process in Swift.
When I run the app in debug mode, it is correct, but when I run it in production mode, the process exited after two seconds. Also, I have disabled the sandbox

```
    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
    process.arguments = ["-c", "/Desktop/ssh-tunnel.sh"]
    process.standardOutput = pipe

    try process.run()
    process.waitUntilExit()
```